# ADXL335 accelerometer just reads high when using breadboard

Tags: arduino, analog, sensor, troubleshooting

I am using an ADXL335 accelerometer connected to an Arduino Nano 5V. For some reason, the accelerometer only reads the highest possible value.

As some context, I am only working with the sensor and the Arduino, and no other external circuit is connected. After moving the sensor's location on the breadboard, it magically works. I have checked various resources, and the wiring doesn't seem to be the problem, and I know the accelerometer works depending on where it is placed on the breadboard.

I have run into the same issue with 2 of the same accelerometers and 2 different breadboards. As an additional detail, when I measured the voltage between each of the coordinate pins and the ground pin, I got approximately 0 V.

The image features an Arduino Uno, but I used an Arduino Nano.

What might be causing the problem?

[image]

Comment: There is almost no technical content in your question so it is impossible to answer specifically. Please edit your question and add a schematic showing the existing circuit, to start with.

Comment: What's the circuit? What's the layout? What's the orentation of the accelerometer?

Comment: As already stated, you have given so little information, it is something like a projective test to help. For reasons not completely clear to me, I am going to bite. 1) You have the circuit (probably a module) configured such that the ST (self test) pin is operating. From a brief look at the data sheet, in self test mode, it responds with constant values until you change the orientation (giving you the illusion of magic), or 2) you are operating the device at 5V and it does not like that. Am I close :)

Comment: @DrG ,  the ST pin is not operating. I also tested it on 3.3 Volts and still got the same result.

Comment: @nove - ok, well I took a shot. I see that you added a fritzing diagram (that is an UNO and not a nano as you said you were usingz0. If you can add the code you are using and the brand of module, it would help a lot - thanks.

Comment: You got 0V from all pins, including power? It sounds like the power is not connected, then. And it works in different parts of the breadboard? Beware that sometimes certain breadboard "holes" wear out and don't make good connections.

Answer (score 1):

Breadboards are not the best way to prototype IMO. There are several problems with breadboards (the non solder type), the first being they have parasitic capacitance and resistance. Another problem arises with used or cheap breadboards not making good connections. A good way to test this is use a meter in continuity mode and check all the connections from end to end.

Comment: So this isn't just saying "don't do this", I'll add a "try this instead": I would recommend, if you want to use something other than a breadboard, using a stripboard or perfboard for prototyping. You'll need a soldering iron, and in the case of the stripboard also something to cut traces with (I use a drill bit, turned by hand), but you'll get more reliable connections with lower parasitics.

Comment: There is also wire wrapping, but you can also break wires if you aren't careful